# how find location using mongoDB query in java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Im trying to find nearby location using mongodb query in java spring
and it is not working

i added the query and the json object that represnts the collection

the type and date are working

```
    @Query("{'type': ?0, 'objectDetails.date': {'$gt': ?1 }, " +
            "'objectDetails.location': {'$near': {'$geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [?2, ?3]}, '$maxDistance': ?4}}}")
    public List<SuperAppObjectEntity> searchEventByLocation(String type, Date now, Double lat, Double lng, Double distance, Pageable pageable);
```

```json
{
  "_id": "2023b.LiorAriely_13e74df2-9ffd-4f30-b641-197633c54856",
  "type": "EVENT",
  "alias": "event",
  "active": true,
  "creationTimestamp": {
    "$date": "2023-05-19T13:27:48.800Z"
  },
  "createdBy": "2023b.LiorAriely_demo@gmail.com",
  "objectDetails": {
    "email": "demo@gmail.com",
    "name": "test",
    "phoneNumber": "123456789",
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -73.99408,
        40.75057
      ]
    },
    "preferences": [
      "anime"
    ],
    "gender": "Male",
    "date": {
      "$date": "2024-07-10T11:00:55.000Z"
    },
    "attendees": [
      "demo@gmail.com"
    ]
  },
  "children": [],
  "_class": "superapp.data.SuperAppObjectEntity"
}
```

Comment: In what way is it 'not working'? Are you getting an error or unexpected results or something else?

Comment: getting un error

Comment: _What_ error? Without sharing it I'm not sure how we can help you solve it